# How I can catch and save to file data from form sended by AJAX in ColdFusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have the followign JavaScript code:

```
function upload(blob) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "test.cfm";

      xhr.onload=function(e) {
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
      }
    };
    var fd=new FormData();
    fd.append("randomname",blob);
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.send(fd); }
```

How can I catch it on server side by ColdFusion and Save blob object to File?
Can someone please some code sample. Thx.
PS. I am pretty new in CF.

Comment: The easiest way to capture form data on the server is to submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using formdata, you can access the form variable with ajax, just like you would with normal http requests.

```
#form.randomname# 
#form['randomname']#
```

So you could save the content in a file with

```
<cfscript>
fileWrite( 'c:\myfile.txt', form.randomname );
</cfscript>
```